# How to perform language translation of a column (excel file) to english using Textblob?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, textblob

My code produced the following error:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'translate'

More detail:

[image: error]

What is wrong with my code?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from textblob import TextBlob

df_file2= df_file['Repair Details']. apply.translate(from_lang='zh-CN',to ='en')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `TextBlob`'s `translate` method.

Assuming `df_file['Repair Details']` have TextBlob objects:

`df_file2= df_file['Repair Details'].apply(lambda x: x.translate(from_lang='zh-CN',to ='en'))`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you accidentally inserted a space before `apply`.

Change this:

```
df_file2= df_file['Repair Details']. apply.translate(from_lang='zh-CN',to ='en')
```

To this:

```
df_file2= df_file['Repair Details'].apply.translate(from_lang='zh-CN',to ='en')
```